# What is the best design pattern to write switch cases code with lot of cases?

Tags: java, design-patterns, switch-statement

I am writing a code where I need to write lot of switch cases and each case has some business logic which basically is a query from mysql db query. i.e.

```
String computeResult()
{
    //code to connect to mysql
    switch(x)
    {
       case A:
         //executing some query and return the result after some processing
       case B:
         //executing some query and return the result after some processing
       //15 more such cases ahead...
    }
}
```

I am writing this code in java, which is an object oriented language.
I looked into the following options:
Option 1: Writing the whole business logic into 15 seperate methods in the same class, but then I am going the procedural language way.
Option 2: Applying strategy pattern. and create a base class with common code, and then various different strategies each computing a result for a single case. The calls to methods of those classes are still present in the `computeResult()` method. But this will call for a class explosion, 15 more classes will be added to my project. Later if I need to add some more cases, that means adding some more classes, and adding some more case statments in `computeResult()` method.
I dont know any way in which that switch case code can be avoided, that is a hardcoded thing, at max I can put these case name to class mapping in a constants file.

For example:

```
HashMap < String, BaseResultComputer > map
```

which will just map the case names to the respective result computer implementations. So whenever we add one more implementation, we just add one more class, and have to change in that constants file.
Please suggest what is the best design to handle this.

Comment: 15 classes, increasing linearly with the number of cases, is far from being a "class explosion". Your map based solution looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, still waiting if someone has a better idea.

Comment: Lose the switch statement and have 15 classes with their own implementations of `computeResult()`.

Comment: That is a map kind of approach I mentioned in the end.

Comment: https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Comment: Thanks David for sharing this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, i will use strategy pattern for this case, there are no worries if we will have a lot of class since we work under java, a language that is purely object-oriented, secondly the solution accepts to the future agrees to be updated with a flexibility, and simplicity to inject the new functionality.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a recurring question on StackOverflow, but usually someone has a handful of else-ifs and wants to refactor it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20else-if%20refactor). Rather than duplicate the answer to those questions, I would like to make a point:

Just because you are using an object-oriented language, doesn't mean everything has to be turned into a design pattern! Try to code things in a way that makes existing complexity more manageable, rather than increases complexity. If you create 15 classes full of boilerplate code and one line of business logic, is that really more desirable than a single switch statement?

Principles to keep in mind:

1. KISS = Keep it Simple Stupid.
2. YAGNI = You Aren't Going to Need It.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I wrote 15 different classes, I meant those classes will have different queries altogether, and no common code whatsoever. Whatever is common, I will keep in the common base class.